# Rename multiple files based on pattern in Unix

Tags: file, unix, rename, batch-rename

There are multiple files in a directory that begin with prefix `fgh`, for example:

```
fghfilea
fghfileb
fghfilec
```

I want to rename all of them to begin with prefix `jkl`. Is there a single command to do that instead of renaming each file individually?

Comment: Related question: [Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25597051/2654678).

Answer (score 367):

There are several ways, but using `rename` will probably be the easiest.

Using one version of [`rename`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/rename/file-rename.1p.en.html) ([Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727288/12574)):

```
rename 's/^fgh/jkl/' fgh*
```

Using another version of [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) (same as [Judy2K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-at-once-in-unix/1086519#1086519)):

```
rename fgh jkl fgh*
```

You should check your platform's man page to see which of the above applies.

Comment: +1 Didn't even know about rename ... Now I can stop using a for loop with mv and sed ... Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this will work? Or, did you mix up a couple of streams from your mind on the same line?

Comment: Works on my machine (Ubuntu 8.10).

Comment: @nik I suppose you're talking to Stephan202 -- Looking at the man page, it really doesn't mention regexes, so you might be right. It still seems to be the right tool: rename fgh jkl fgh* should really do the right thing.

Comment: Whichever way -- rename is the answer.

Comment: Wow. you're right. The man page on my machine is very different from the one I linked... I'll update the answer in a sec. My apologies!

Comment: You are linking to a different `rename` then you are showing syntax for http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rename is the other one

Comment: @Stephan202, now please don't tell me you also have a perl script called rename :-)

Comment: Good one Hasterkun, i was expecting something like that tripped Stephan.

Comment: @Stephan202: I did not understand `rename` yet. Now, I can have a look at it. Thank you. :-)

Comment: @Alan, yes, Stephan's line can actually go into the `rename` man page. He should retain it under his corrected answer.

Comment: Thanks all for clarifying the situation! (@nik: it is written in Perl, yes :)

Comment: I never came across that before. Definitely non-standard. It's also on RHEL5 but *not* Solaris 10.

Comment: Not present on all *nix systems. Not on Max OS X for one, and no package in fink to get it. Haven't looked at MacPorts.

Comment: AFAICT, `rename` seems to be a Linux specific script or utility.  If you care at all about portability, please continue using `sed` and loops or an inline Perl script.

Comment: `brew install rename` on OS X :)

Comment: Annoyingly, the one supporting regexes is `perl-rename` on Arch Linux.

Comment: For those interested, I successfully installed the rename utility on Mac OS/X just by copying the script's source to "/usr/bin/rename" and assigning executable permissions: http://tips.webdesign10.com/files/rename.pl.txt

Working beautifully. :-) Running Mavericks on a MacBook Pro Retina.

Comment: Append-to-filename example for multiple json files (Mac `brew install rename` version): `rename -AFOO *.json`
    Delete string example: `rename -DFOO *.json`

Comment: version is definitely important, on CentOS, it is v2.

Comment: Had to install it on Windows Subsystem for Linux using `apt install`. The first syntax works on the WSL version.

Comment: There are ALWAYS several ways.  :)

Comment: A post to guide you with Perl's rename: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727288/12574

Answer (score 149):

This is how `sed` and `mv` can be used together to do rename:

```
for f in fgh*; do mv "$f" $(echo "$f" | sed 's/^fgh/jkl/g'); done
```

As per comment below, if the file names have spaces in them, quotes may need to *surround* the sub-function that returns the name to move the files to:

```
for f in fgh*; do mv "$f" "$(echo $f | sed 's/^fgh/jkl/g')"; done
```

Comment: Very close. Note that you only want to match the first occurrence of fgh: 's/^fgh/jkl/g' (The caret makes all the difference).

Comment: Just for the sake of precision...  You mean "fgh at the beginning of the name", not "the first occurrence of fgh".  /^fgh/ will match "fghi", but not "efgh".

Comment: @Stephan, That was a typo on my part (fixed it).

Comment: @Dave: correct. Since only filenames matching fgh* are processed, these notions coincide in this particular case. But indeed I could have been more precise.

Comment: Thanks. very useful on my Mac that hasn't got `rename` installed by default. Sed does the trick :)

Comment: If you do not have access to "rename" this works great. The code may require quotes if your file names include spaces. `for f in fgh*; do mv "$f" "$(echo $f | sed 's/^fgh/jkl/g')"; done`

Comment: The `rename` command didn't really work. The `sed` command line above though worked on the first try.

Comment: @nik Without quotes renaming this list of files would throw an error: `touch fghfilea fghfileb fghfilec fghfile\ d`. I kindly suggest to take into consideration @DaveNelson remarks.

Comment: I guess there's also no need for the g modifier if you only want to match the first occurrence.

Comment: Also, if doing more complex patterns, be aware of sed's regex syntax. For example, sed does not do `\d` for digits; it does `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]`; and not `+`, but `\+`.

Answer (score 95):

rename might not be in every system. so if you don't have it, use the shell
this example in bash shell

```
for f in fgh*; do mv "$f" "${f/fgh/xxx}";done
```

Comment: In this solution, `sed` command is not required. This one is simpler than @nik's answer.

Comment: xxx stands for the replacement? in case of the original poster, that would have been "jkl"

Comment: The cleanest solution of them all.

Comment: Perhaps point out more emphatically that this is a Bash extension which doesn't exist in POSIX `sh` or generally in other shells.

Comment: Sweet -- there are so many obscure corners in the Unix world -- never seen this one  before.

Comment: Thank You!
I used it for my requirement as below,

for f in `ls`; do mv $f $f.txt; done

And no need to install anything.

Answer (score 47):

Using [mmv](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/mln.1.html):

```
mmv "fgh*" "jkl#1"
```

Comment: Wow, this is an excellent and simple way of solving the problem! Glad to be introduced to mmv, thanks!

Comment: Thanks!!! Had never heard of mmv before. Just installed and been playing with it - simple, powerful.

Comment: if you want to batch rename recursively use `;` in conjunction with `#1`. example: `mmv ";fgh*" "#1jkl#2"`

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Capture groups with '*' and call them back with #1,#2,...  EX: mmv "my show ep* 1080p.*" "my.show.#1.#2" = my.show.001.avi

Comment: most appropriate solution

Comment: Maybe as a note for the lazy reader: `#1` contains just the content of what was matched by `*`

Answer (score 22):

There are many ways to do it (not all of these will work on all unixy systems):

- `ls | cut -c4- | xargs -I§ mv fgh§ jkl§`

  The § may be replaced by anything you find convenient. You could do this with `find -exec` too but that behaves subtly different on many systems, so I usually avoid that
- `for f in fgh*; do mv "$f" "${f/fgh/jkl}";done`

  Crude but effective as they say
- `rename 's/^fgh/jkl/' fgh*`

  Real pretty, but rename is not present on BSD, which is the most common unix system afaik.
- `rename fgh jkl fgh*`
- `ls | perl -ne 'chomp; next unless -e; $o = $_; s/fgh/jkl/; next if -e; rename $o, $_';`

  If you insist on using Perl, but there is no rename on your system, you can use this monster.

Some of those are a bit convoluted and the list is far from complete, but you will find what you want here for pretty much all unix systems.

Comment: i love this kind of monster !

Comment: yeah, i still have a weak spot for perl too :)

Comment: note that [`ls` output should not be parsed and/or piped](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Comment: The Perl monster here happens to work flawlessly if you have spaces in your filenames.

Answer (score 18):

```
rename fgh jkl fgh*
```

Comment: On my machine this produces the error 'Bareword "fgh" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 1) line 1.'

Comment: @Stephan202, what is your machine?

Comment: Ubuntu 8.10 (perl v5.10.0 / 2009-06-26)

Comment: @Stephan202 I have the same issue, did you resolve? (7 years later)

Comment: @whossname: sorry, really can't remember. (Slow reply due to holiday.)

Comment: @Stephan202 I ended up solving this and I've already forgotten what the answer was

Comment: This isn't a Perl command, it's a shell command. "Quit Perl and try again" is the solution to this!

Answer (score 16):

Using `find`, `xargs` and `sed`:

```
find . -name "fgh*" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'mv "{}" "$(dirname "{}")/`echo $(basename "{}") | sed 's/^fgh/jkl/g'`"'
```

It's more complex than [@nik's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086545/102353) but it allows to rename files recursively. For instance, the structure,

```
.
├── fghdir
│   ├── fdhfilea
│   └── fghfilea
├── fghfile\ e
├── fghfilea
├── fghfileb
├── fghfilec
└── other
    ├── fghfile\ e
    ├── fghfilea
    ├── fghfileb
    └── fghfilec
```

would be transformed to this,

```
.
├── fghdir
│   ├── fdhfilea
│   └── jklfilea
├── jklfile\ e
├── jklfilea
├── jklfileb
├── jklfilec
└── other
    ├── jklfile\ e
    ├── jklfilea
    ├── jklfileb
    └── jklfilec
```

The key to make it work with `xargs` is to [invoke the shell from xargs](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Invoking-the-shell-from-xargs.html).

Comment: I was going to post something like this, but it would have taken me an hour to get the right command

Comment: The recursion this answer allows for makes it really robust—I just quickly renamed thousands of files in a deeply-nested hierarchy.

Comment: This should be the excepted answer.

Comment: No, the command is dangerous. God, please do NOT do that. It will make a mess of your directories.

Answer (score 6):

Generic command would be

`find /path/to/files -name '<search>*' -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0/<search>/<replace>}' {} \;`

where `<search>` and `<replace>` should be replaced with your source and target respectively.

As a more specific example tailored to your problem (should be run from the same folder where your files are), the above command would look like:

`find . -name 'gfh*' -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0/gfh/jkl}' {} \;`

For a "dry run" add `echo` before `mv`, so that you'd see what commands are generated:

`find . -name 'gfh*' -exec bash -c 'echo mv $0 ${0/gfh/jkl}' {} \;`

Answer (score 3):

To install the Perl [rename](https://metacpan.org/module/rename) script:

```
sudo cpan install File::Rename
```

There are [two renames](http://oylenshpeegul.typepad.com/blog/2011/12/a-tale-of-two-renames.html) as mentioned in the comments in Stephan202's answer.
Debian based distros have the [Perl rename](https://metacpan.org/module/rename). Redhat/rpm distros have the [C rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename).
OS X doesn't have one installed by default (at least in 10.8), neither does Windows/Cygwin.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it using command-line Groovy:

```bsh
groovy -e 'new File(".").eachFileMatch(~/fgh.*/) {it.renameTo(it.name.replaceFirst("fgh", "jkl"))}'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh

#replace all files ended witn .f77 to .f90 in a directory

for filename in *.f77
do 
    #echo $filename
    #b= echo $filename | cut -d. -f1
    #echo $b    
    mv "${filename}" "${filename%.f77}.f90"    
done
```

Answer (score 2):

On Solaris you can try:

```
for file in `find ./ -name "*TextForRename*"`; do 
    mv -f "$file" "${file/TextForRename/NewText}"
done
```

Comment: You get half a point for quoting the file names *inside* the loop, but `for file in $(find)` is fundamentally flawed and cannot be corrected with quoting. If `find` returns `./file name with spaces` you will get a `for` loop over `./file`, `name`, `with`, and `spaces` and no amount of quoting inside the loop will help (or even be necessary).

Answer (score 2):

This script worked for me for recursive renaming with directories/file names possibly containing white-spaces:

```
find . -type f -name "*\;*" | while read fname; do
    dirname=`dirname "$fname"`
    filename=`basename "$fname"`
    newname=`echo "$filename" | sed -e "s/;/ /g"`
    mv "${dirname}/$filename" "${dirname}/$newname"
done
```

Notice the `sed` expression which in this example replaces all occurrences of `;` with space . This should of course be replaced according to the specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

Using [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer):

```
$ renamer --find /^fgh/ --replace jkl * --dry-run
```

Remove the `--dry-run` flag once you're happy the output looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using my own script, which solves this problem. It also has options to change the encoding of the file names, and to convert combining diacriticals to precomposed characters, a problem I always have when I copy files from my Mac.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Copyright (c) 2014 André von Kugland

# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a
# copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"),
# to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation
# the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense,
# and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
# Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
# all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
# FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
# DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

$help_msg =
"rename.pl, a script to rename files in batches, using Perl
           expressions to transform their names.
Usage:
    rename.pl [options] FILE1 [FILE2 ...]
Where options can be:
    -v                      Verbose.
    -vv                     Very verbose.
    --apply                 Really apply modifications.
    -e PERLCODE             Execute PERLCODE. (e.g. 's/a/b/g')
    --from-charset=CS       Source charset. (e.g. \"iso-8859-1\")
    --to-charset=CS         Destination charset. (e.g. \"utf-8\")
    --unicode-normalize=NF  Unicode normalization form. (e.g. \"KD\")
    --basename              Modifies only the last element of the path.
";

use Encode;
use Getopt::Long;
use Unicode::Normalize 'normalize';
use File::Basename;
use I18N::Langinfo qw(langinfo CODESET);

Getopt::Long::Configure ("bundling");

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                                           Our variables.                                        #
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

my $apply = 0;
my $verbose = 0;
my $help = 0;
my $debug = 0;
my $basename = 0;
my $unicode_normalize = "";
my @scripts;
my $from_charset = "";
my $to_charset = "";
my $codeset = "";

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                                        Get cmdline options.                                     #
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

$result = GetOptions ("apply" => \$apply,
                      "verbose|v+" => \$verbose,
                      "execute|e=s" => \@scripts,
                      "from-charset=s" => \$from_charset,
                      "to-charset=s" => \$to_charset,
                      "unicode-normalize=s" => \$unicode_normalize,
                      "basename" => \$basename,
                      "help|h|?" => \$help,
                      "debug" => \$debug);

# If not going to apply, then be verbose.
if (!$apply && $verbose == 0) {
  $verbose = 1;
}

if ((($#scripts == -1)
  && (($from_charset eq "") || ($to_charset eq ""))
  && $unicode_normalize eq "")
  || ($#ARGV == -1) || ($help)) {
  print $help_msg;
  exit(0);
}

if (($to_charset ne "" && $from_charset eq "")
  ||($from_charset eq "" && $to_charset ne "")
  ||($to_charset eq "" && $from_charset eq "" && $unicode_normalize ne "")) {
  $codeset = langinfo(CODESET);
  $to_charset = $codeset if $from_charset ne "" && $to_charset eq "";
  $from_charset = $codeset if $from_charset eq "" && $to_charset ne "";
}

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#         Composes the filter function using the @scripts array and possibly other options.       #
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

$f = "sub filterfunc() {\n    my \$s = shift;\n";
$f .= "    my \$d = dirname(\$s);\n    my \$s = basename(\$s);\n" if ($basename != 0);
$f .= "    for (\$s) {\n";
$f .= "        $_;\n" foreach (@scripts);   # Get scripts from '-e' opt. #
# Handle charset translation and normalization.
if (($from_charset ne "") && ($to_charset ne "")) {
  if ($unicode_normalize eq "") {
    $f .= "        \$_ = encode(\"$to_charset\", decode(\"$from_charset\", \$_));\n";
  } else {
    $f .= "        \$_ = encode(\"$to_charset\", normalize(\"$unicode_normalize\", decode(\"$from_charset\", \$_)));\n"
  }
} elsif (($from_charset ne "") || ($to_charset ne "")) {
    die "You can't use `from-charset' nor `to-charset' alone";
} elsif ($unicode_normalize ne "") {
  $f .= "        \$_ = encode(\"$codeset\", normalize(\"$unicode_normalize\", decode(\"$codeset\", \$_)));\n"
}
$f .= "    }\n";
$f .= "    \$s = \$d . '/' . \$s;\n" if ($basename != 0);
$f .= "    return \$s;\n}\n";
print "Generated function:\n\n$f" if ($debug);

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                 Evaluates the filter function body, so to define it in our scope.               #
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

eval $f;

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                  Main loop, which passes names through filters and renames files.               #
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

foreach (@ARGV) {
  $old_name = $_;
  $new_name = filterfunc($_);

  if ($old_name ne $new_name) {
    if (!$apply or (rename $old_name, $new_name)) {
      print "`$old_name' => `$new_name'\n" if ($verbose);
    } else {
      print "Cannot rename `$old_name' to `$new_name'.\n";
    }
  } else {
    print "`$old_name' unchanged.\n" if ($verbose > 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: As predicted by **@kleopatra**, the link has gotten `stale over time`

Comment: @y2k-shubham , not anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Using [StringSolver](https://github.com/MikaelMayer/StringSolver) tools (windows & Linux bash) which process by examples:

```
filter fghfilea ok fghreport ok notfghfile notok; mv --all --filter fghfilea jklfilea
```

It first **computes a filter based on examples**, where the input is the file names and the output (ok and notok, arbitrary strings). If filter had the option --auto or was invoked alone after this command, it would create a folder `ok` and a folder `notok` and push files respectively to them.

Then using the filter, the **`mv` command is a semi-automatic move** which becomes automatic with the modifier --auto. Using the previous filter thanks to --filter, it finds a mapping from `fghfilea` to `jklfilea` and then applies it on all filtered files.

---

*Other one-line solutions*

Other equivalent ways of doing the same (each line is equivalent), so you can choose your favorite way of doing it.

```
filter fghfilea ok fghreport ok notfghfile notok; mv --filter fghfilea jklfilea; mv
filter fghfilea ok fghreport ok notfghfile notok; auto --all --filter fghfilea "mv fghfilea jklfilea"
# Even better, automatically infers the file name
filter fghfilea ok fghreport ok notfghfile notok; auto --all --filter "mv fghfilea jklfilea"
```

*Multi-step solution*

To carefully find if the commands are performing well, you can type the following:

```
filter fghfilea ok
filter fghfileb ok
filter fghfileb notok
```

and when you are confident that the filter is good, perform the first move:

```
mv fghfilea jklfilea
```

If you want to test, and use the previous filter, type:

```
mv --test --filter
```

If the transformation is not what you wanted (e.g. even with `mv --explain` you see that something is wrong), you can type `mv --clear` to restart moving files, or add more examples `mv input1 input2` where input1 and input2 are other examples

When you are confident, just type

```
mv --filter
```

and voilà! All the renaming is done using the filter.

DISCLAIMER: I am a co-author of this work made for academic purposes. There might also be a bash-producing feature soon.

Answer (score 1):

It was much easier (on my Mac) to do this in Ruby. Here are 2 examples:

```
# for your fgh example. renames all files from "fgh..." to "jkl..."
files = Dir['fgh*']

files.each do |f|
  f2 = f.gsub('fgh', 'jkl')
  system("mv #{f} #{f2}")
end

# renames all files in directory from "021roman.rb" to "021_roman.rb"
files = Dir['*rb'].select {|f| f =~ /^[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]+/}

files.each do |f|
  f1 = f.clone
  f2 = f.insert(3, '_')
  system("mv #{f1} #{f2}")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

My version of renaming mass files:

```
for i in *; do
    echo "mv $i $i"
done |
sed -e "s#from_pattern#to_pattern#g” > result1.sh
sh result1.sh
```

Comment: I like the ability to verify before running the script

Comment: This breaks magnificently on file names containing spaces, quotes, or other shell metacharacters.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```bash
for f in fgh*; do mv -- "$f" "jkl${f:3}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using regexp:

I wanted files to be renamed like this:

```
file0001.txt -> 1.txt
ofile0002.txt -> 2.txt 
f_i_l_e0003.txt -> 3.txt
```

usig  the  [a-z|_]+0*([0-9]+.*) regexp where  ([0-9]+.*) is a group substring to use on the rename command

```
ls -1 | awk 'match($0, /[a-z|\_]+0*([0-9]+.*)/, arr) { print   arr[0]  " "  arr[1] }'|xargs  -l mv
```

Produces:

```
mv file0001.txt 1.txt
mv ofile0002.txt 2.txt
mv f_i_l_e0003.txt 3.txt
```

Another example:

```
file001abc.txt -> abc1.txt
ofile0002abcd.txt -> abcd2.txt 

ls -1 | awk 'match($0, /[a-z|\_]+0*([0-9]+.*)([a-z]+)/, arr) { print   arr[0]  " "  arr[2] arr[1] }'|xargs  -l mv
```

Produces:

```
  mv file001abc.txt abc1.txt
  mv ofile0002abcd.txt abcd2.txt
```

Warning, be careful.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this script to search for all .mkv files recursively renaming found files to .avi. You can customize it to your neeeds. I've added some other things such as getting file directory, extension, file name from a file path just incase you need to refer to something in the future.

```
find . -type f -name "*.mkv" | while read fp; do 
fd=$(dirname "${fp}");
fn=$(basename "${fp}");
ext="${fn##*.}";
f="${fn%.*}";
new_fp="${fd}/${f}.avi"
mv -v "$fp" "$new_fp" 
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic script to run a `sed` expression on a list of files (combines the [`sed` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086545/393280) with the [`rename` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086509/393280)):

```
#!/bin/sh

e=$1
shift

for f in $*; do
    fNew=$(echo "$f" | sed "$e")
    mv "$f" "$fNew";
done
```

Invoke by passing the script a `sed` expression, and then any list of files, just like a version of [`rename`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086509/393280):

```
script.sh 's/^fgh/jkl/' fgh*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below script. it is very easy to run on terminal...

**//Rename multiple files at a time**

```
for file in  FILE_NAME*
do
    mv -i "${file}" "${file/FILE_NAME/RENAMED_FILE_NAME}"
done
```

**Example:-**

```
for file in  hello*
do
    mv -i "${file}" "${file/hello/JAISHREE}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended version of the `find` + `sed` + `xargs` solution.

Original solutions: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24004045/2228771) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40029320/2228771).

### Requirements: search, prune, regex, rename

1. I want to rename multiple files in many folders.
2. Some folders should be pruned/excluded.
3. I am on `cygwin` and cannot get `perl rename` to work, which is required for [the most popular solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086509/2228771) (and I assume it to be slow, since it does not seem to have a pruning option?)

### Solution

1. Use `find` to get files effectively (with pruning), and with many customization options.
2. Use `sed` for regex replacement.
3. Use `xargs` to funnel the result into the final command.

### Example 1: rename `*.js` files but ignore `node_modules`

This example finds files and echos the found file and the renamed file. For safety reasons, it does not move anything for now. You have to replace `echo` with `mv` for that.

```bash
set -x # stop on error
set -e # verbose mode (echo all commands)

find "." -type f -not \( -path "**/node_modules/**" -prune \) -name "*.js" | 
  sed -nE "s/(.*)\/my(.*)/& \1\/YOUR\2/p" |
  xargs -n 2 echo  # echo first (replace with `mv` later)
```

The above script turns this:

```
./x/y/my-abc.js
```

Into this:

```
./x/y/YOUR-abc.js
```

### Breakdown of Solution

1. `find "." -type f -not \( -path "**/node_modules/**" -prune \) -name "*.js"`

   - Searches for files (`-type f`).
   - The `-not` part excludes (and, importantly does not traverse!) the (notoriously ginormous) `node_modules` folder.
   - File name must match `"*.js"`.
   - You can add more include and exclude clauses.
   - Refs:

     - [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905054/how-can-i-recursively-find-all-files-in-current-and-subfolders-based-on-wildcard) discusses recursive file finding alternatives.
     - [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595367) discusses aspects of pruning and excluding.
     - [man find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)
2. `sed -nE "s/(.*)\/my\-(.*\.js)/& \1\/YOUR-\2/p"`

   - NOTE: `sed` always takes some getting used to.
   - `-E` enables "extended" (i.e. more modern) regex syntax.
   - `-n` is used in combination with the trailing `/p` flag: `-n` hides all results, while `/p` will print only matching results. This way, we only see/move files that need changing, and ignore all others.
   - Replacement regex with `sed` (and other regex tools) is always of the format: `s/regex/replacement/FLAGS`
   - In replacement, the `&` represents the matched input string. This will be the first argument to `mv`.
   - Refs:

     - [linux regex tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/linux-regular-expressions.html)
     - [man sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)
3. `xargs -n 2 echo`

   - Run the command `echo` with (the first two strings of) the replaced string.
   - Refs: [man xargs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is only a concrete application of what is explained in other answers, I hope it will be useful:

I went in a case where I had to rename some properties files that were in the form `CodeAPE_fr.properties` to `CodeAPE.properties`, in a whole directory and I did:

```bash
for i in `dir`; do mv $i `echo $i | sed 's/_fr.properties/.properties/g'`; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight improvement/adjustment that you need if the filenames have whitespaces AND you want to filter based on the portion of the filename that has the pattern with the whitespaces:

```
for f in "Filename With Spaces"*; do mv "$f" "$(echo $f | sed 's/^Filename With Spaces/FilenameWithNoMoreSpaces/g')"; done
```

The key difference in my answer is that you need to put quotation marks around the "Filename With Spaces" if that is the portion of the filename that you want to use as the filter to choose which files to operate on.  The previous answer(s) mentioned filename with spaces but then selected files based on jkl* which does not have spaces.

Note: You do not have to replace with FilenameWithNoMoreSpaces.  I just wanted to show a typical use case as an example.

If the pattern with the whitespace is in the MIDDLE of the filename, then the adjusted command would follow this pattern:

```
for f in *"Spaces In Middle of Filename"*; do mv "$f" "$(echo $f | sed 's/Spaces In Middle of Filename/FilenameWithNoMoreSpaces/g')"; done
```

Notice, I added another asterisk to the beginning of the filename pattern with spaces that is in the double quotes and I removed the carat ^ from the "find" part of the sed command.  My apologies if I'm over-explaining.  I'm taking into account that some people who read this might be completely new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

With nautilus:

- select file want to rename by pattern
- Press Ctrl-F2
- Choose "Find and replace text"
- Enter pattern and the replacementt text
- Press "Rename"

[image]