# Rename files using a regex with bash

Tags: regex, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [rename multiple files at once in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-at-once-in-unix)

I would like to rename all files from a folder using a regex (add a name to the end of name) and move to another folder.

It my opinion, it should be looking like this:

```
mv -v ./images/*.png ./test/*test.png
```

but it does not work.

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: Essentially the same as many other questions - such as SO 1086502 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/).  There was one asked yesterday, even.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate per se. I wanted to use a *regex capture*, as I had filenames like `blah_blah_15_blah_blah_948ABCD.txt` and the important part for me was the first number, whereas the second number was some kind of checksum. The capture is shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1961273/1168342

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try this:

```
for x in *.png;do mv $x test/${x%.png}test.png;done
```

Comment: here's what it returns:
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

Comment: @mxg: sorry, I did not give 100% correct command: you need `cd images` first and prepend `test/` with `..`

Comment: You should put quotes around the variable names in case there are spaces in the filenames: `for x in *.png; do mv "$x" "test/${x%.png}test.png"; done`

Comment: It works, but it leaves one file in the folder.

@catwalk, you're not paid to give solutions, but 'paid' to give good indications:)
Thanks!

Comment: actually, if the filenames contain spaces, you're screwed with `for` with or without quotes.  that's why it's better to use the *generator | while read line; do something with "$line"; done* idiom.  in this case: `ls | grep '\.png$' | while read x; do ... ; done`

Comment: It is very useful for me now!

Comment: @justsomebody: simply use IFS=$'\n'; in front of your line then

Comment: Isn't that using globs and not regex?

Comment: @menssana: if you "simply" set `IFS` it would be good to set it back to whatever it was beforehand for the sake of the next commands that might use that mechanism.

Answer (score 138):

If you are on a linux, check special [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) command which would do just that - renaming using regular expressions.

```
rename 's/^images\/(.+)/test\/$1.png/s' images/*.png
```

Otherwise, write a bash cycle over the filenames as [catwalk suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961255/rename-files-using-a-regex-with-bash/1961270#1961270).

Comment: It may be called `prename` on some systems.

Comment: much less to remember / type, thanks! `rename 's/_20/ /g' *.mp4`

Comment: The best, simplest way to do it. Although the answer might be edited  to give some examples like memeLab did.

Comment: also available on mac via homebrew `brew install rename`

Comment: I got here because I wanted to use a capture `$1` in the destination name, to rename files like `blah_blah_15_blah_blah_948ABCD1.txt` to `15.txt` via `'s/blah_blah(\d\d)blah_blah([0-9A-F]{8})/$1/'`

Comment: If you have to rename a lot of files (happened in my case) it's better to use `find ... -type f ... | xargs rename 's/-//g'` - otherwise you may get "Argument list too long"

Comment: To be clear, it's the `rename` from [pstray](https://github.com/pstray/rename), not [util-linux](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux). Many systems have the latter installed by default, but not the former. This got me confused for a few minutes into thinking that it's some kind of weirdly under-documented tool.

Answer (score 60):

```
$ for old in ./images*.png; do
    new=$(echo $old | sed -e 's/\.png$/test.png/')
    mv -v "$old" "$new"
  done
```

Comment: I like the use of sed since it allows me to replace this with whatever I like.  in my case replace "%20" with " ".  I used the 'g' at the end of the regex to allow that:
for old in *.pdf; do new=$( echo $old | sed -e 's/\%20/ /g'); mv $old "$new";done

Comment: Thanks! I derived the one-liner `mv file_20name.mp4 "$(echo file_20name.mp4 | sed -e 's/_20/ /g')"` from this

Comment: beautiful as this allows full  power of sed regex syntax.  Great combination of commands, and good prototype for many other bash scripts.

Comment: This worked beautifully for what I needed (removing underscores from file names). `for old in \`ls\`; do new=$(echo $old | sed -e 's/_//g'); mv "$old" "$new"; done`

Comment: I looked at the docs for `-e` flags but don't understand what it does

Comment: I think this is beautiful combination of sed and other bash programs.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another solution would be a tool called [mmv](https://github.com/itchyny/mmv):

```bash
mmv "./images/*.png" "./test/#1test.png"
```