# One liner to rename bunch of files

Tags: linux, file, rename

I was looking for a linux command line one-liner to rename a bunch of files in one shot.

```
pattern1.a  pattern1.b pattern1.c ...
```

Once the command is executed I should get

```
pattern2.a  pattern2.b pattern2.c ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename multiple files in Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-in-unix)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you happen to be using Linux, you may also have a perl script at /usr/bin/rename (sometimes installed as "prename") which can rename files based on more complex patterns than shell globbing permits.

The /usr/bin/rename on one of my systems is documented [here](http://www.unix.com/man-page/All/1/rename/).  It could be used like this:

```
rename "s/pattern1/pattern2/" pattern1.*
```

A number of [other Linux environments](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rename&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=SuSE+Linux%2Fi386+ES+10+SP1&arch=default&format=html) seem to have a different `rename` that might be used like this:

```
rename pattern1 pattern2 pattern1.*
```

Check `man rename` on your system for details.

Comment: Thumbs up for the second rename example; searched all over the web and couldn't find the problem why the `"s/pattern1/pattern2/"` didn't work!

Answer (score 13):

```
for i in pattern1.*; do mv -- "$i" "${i/pattern1/pattern2}"; done
```

Before you run it, stick an `echo` in front of the `mv` to see what it *would* do.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of ways to skin this cat.  If you'd prefer your pattern to be a regex rather than a fileglob, and you'd like to do the change recursively you could use something like this:

```
find . -print | sed -ne '/^\.\/pattern1\(\..*\)/s//mv "&" "pattern2\1"/p'
```

As Kerrek suggested with his answer, this one first shows you what it would do.  Pipe the output through a shell (i.e. add `| sh` to the end) once you're comfortable with the commands.

This works for me:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ ls -l foo.*
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel  0 Mar 26 13:59 foo.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel  0 Mar 26 13:59 foo.txt
[ghoti@pc ~]$ find . -print | sed -ne '/^\.\/foo\(\..*\)/s//mv "&" "bar\1"/p'
mv "./foo.txt" "bar.txt"
mv "./foo.php" "bar.php"
[ghoti@pc ~]$ find . -print | sed -ne '/^\.\/foo\(\..*\)/s//mv "&" "bar\1"/p' | sh
[ghoti@pc ~]$ ls -l foo.* bar.*
ls: foo.*: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel  0 Mar 26 13:59 bar.php
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel  0 Mar 26 13:59 bar.txt
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```