# Multiple file rename unix

Tags: macos, unix, file-rename

I am new to unix (using the Mac OS X terminal) and am trying to rename certain files by adding some text in the middle of the filename. For all files in the folder ./temp I would like to replace filenames beginning `dr_ic0004` with `dr_ic0004_DMN`.

For example
`dr_0004_tstat1.txt` and `dr_0004_tstat2.txt` with
`dr_0004_DMN_tstat1.txt` and `dr_0004_DMN_tstat2.txt`
respectively.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename multiple files in Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-in-unix)

Comment: You'll need a for to capture the names, then you'll need to process the name with sed or gawk or something to create the new name. Type man sed to look up it's syntax.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  We'd love to help.  What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. This worked:
for i in dr_ 0004*; do mv $i $(echo $i | sed 's/^dr_0004/dr_ 0004_DMN/'); done

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suppose you had `dr_ic0004foo`, `dr_ic0004bar` and `dr_ic0004baz`. To see them all, you'd do:

```
ls dr_ic0004*
```

To isolate the variable parts (`foo`, `bar` and `baz`) you could run that list through sed:

```
ls dr_ic0004*|sed 's/^dr_ic0004//'
```

To rename a single file you would use `mv`:

```
mv dr_ic0004foo dr_ic0004_DMNfoo
```

And to iterate over a list, you could use a `for` loop:

```
for x in foo bar baz; do echo $x ; done
```

**Put them all together and you get:**

```
for x in `ls dr_ic0004*|sed 's/^dr_ic0004//'`; do mv dr_ic0004$x dr_ic0004_DMN$x; done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for filename in dr_0004*
do
    mv "$filename" dr_0004_DMN"${filename#dr_0004}"
done
```