# How to use mv command to rename multiple files in unix?

Tags: unix, command, rename, mv

I am trying to rename multiple files with extension `xyz[n]` to extension `xyz`

example :

```
mv *.xyz[1] to *.xyz
```

but the error is coming as - `" *.xyz No such file or directory"`

Comment: This command is trying to move *.xyz[1] to directory *.xyz (if we ignore the "to" in the middle, which is invalid :). Thats why its not working. You'll need a bit of a script to do this.

Comment: filename extension has `[` or `]`. Are you sure?

Comment: Thanks to all for replying

Comment: @Damien but simple mv abc.xyz[1] abc.xyz is working

Comment: @theharshest: Yes I am sure the extension is this only

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename multiple files in Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-in-unix)

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if mv can directly work using * but this would work

```
find ./ -name "*.xyz\[*\]" | while read line
do 
mv "$line" ${line%.*}.xyz
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have some files as shown below.Now i want remove the part -(ab...) from those files.

```
> ls -1 foo*
foo-bar-(ab-4529111094).txt
foo-bar-foo-bar-(ab-189534).txt
foo-bar-foo-bar-bar-(ab-24937932201).txt
```

So the expected file names would be :

```
> ls -1 foo*
foo-bar-foo-bar-bar.txt
foo-bar-foo-bar.txt
foo-bar.txt
>
```

Below is a simple way to do it.

```
> ls -1 | nawk '/foo-bar-/{old=$0;gsub(/-\(.*\)/,"",$0);system("mv \""old"\" "$0)}'
```

for detailed explanation check [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html)

Comment: Thanks Sarathi for replying
When I fired the command on the terminal I got the error as nawk command not found 
Exact O/P is "-bash: nawk: command not found"

Then I tried with awk command as
ls -1 |awk '/110X/{old=$0;gsub(/[/,"",$0);system("mv \""old"\" "$0)}'

and I got the error
"
awk: nonterminated character class [
 source line number 1
 context is
  >>> /110X/{old=$0;gsub(/[/,"",$0) 
"

Comment: My file names are like
20130110X1YZ.rtf[2] 20130110XYZ.rtf[1] 20130110XYZ1.rtf[2]

and I want to remove the [n] values from the name like 20130110X1YZ.rtf for 20130110X1YZ.rtf[2]

Comment: You can try awk instead of nawk.nawk i use on solaris.So it worked on solaris.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using the automated tools of [StringSolver](https://github.com/MikaelMayer/StringSolver). Let us say your first file is named `abc.xyz[1]` a second named `def.xyz[1]` and a third named `ghi.jpg` (not the same extension as the previous two).

First, filter the files you want by giving examples (ok and notok are any words such that the first describes the accepted files):

```
filter abc.xyz[1] ok def.xyz[1] ok ghi.jpg notok
```

Then perform the move with the filter it created:

```
mv abc.xyz[1] abc.xyz
mv --filter --all
```

The second line generalizes the first transformation on all files ending with `.xyz[1]`.

The last two lines can also be abbreviated in just one, which performs the moves and immediately generalizes it:

```
mv --filter --all abc.xyz[1] abc.xyz
```

DISCLAIMER: I am a co-author of this work for academic purposes. Other examples are available on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNFY9azdblQ&list=UUzgLw5m__x6tRoy4wW4OPow&feature=share).

Answer (score 0):

I think mv can't operate on multiple files directly without loop.
Use rename command instead. it uses regular expressions but easy to use once mastered and more powerful.

```
rename 's/^text-to-replace/new-text-you-want/' text-to-replace*
```

e.g to rename all .jar files in a directory to .jar_bak

```
rename 's/^jar/jar_bak/' jar*
```