# How to modify file names in bash

Tags: bash

I have a directory like: `/data/work/files/`

`calldata_phonecalls_2131201401_01.zip
calldata_phonecalls_7373201401_02.zip`

In this directory I want to create new files corresponding to the zipfiles like , but modifying a small part of the name in `BASH`:

`calldata_calllog_2131201401_01.tsv
calldata_calllog_7373201401_02.tsv`

pl note "phonecalls" changed to "calllog"

Pl help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and `basename`:

```
for f in /data/work/files/*.zip; do
  mv "$f" "$(basename "${f/phonecalls/calllog}" .zip).tsv"
done
```

Using `rename` (part of perl distribution):

```
rename 's/phonecalls/calllog/;s/\.zip$/.tsv/' /data/work/files/*.zip
```

Comment: @HomayounAfshari Didn't notice that; should be fixed now.

Comment: @user1189851 Modifications in name?

Comment: excuse me @devnull, can you explain how ${f/x/y} works?

Comment: @HomayounAfshari It'd replace _x_ with _y_.

Comment: is it evaluated by bash?

Comment: @HomayounAfshari Yes, it's called shell parameter expansion.  See the link in the edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Using rename :

Using one version of rename:

```
rename 's/^fgh/jkl/' fgh*
```

Using another version of rename :

```
rename fgh jkl fgh*
```

You should check your platform's man page to see which of the above applies.

Using mv:

```
find ./ -name "*.xyz\[*\]" | while read line
do 
mv "$line" ${line%.*}.xyz
done
```

Another way

```
ls -1 | nawk '/foo-bar-/{old=$0;gsub(/-\(.*\)/,"",$0);system("mv \""old"\" "$0)}'
```

Yet another:

```
for f in fgh*; do mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/^fgh/jkl/g'); done
```

There are several other answers under stackoverflow and superuser pages:

Copied/summarized from the following links:

[Rename multiple files in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-in-unix)

[How to use mv command to rename multiple files in unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967572/how-to-use-mv-command-to-rename-multiple-files-in-unix)