# find a pattern in files and rename them

Tags: linux, bash

I use this command to find files with a given pattern and then rename them to something else

```
find . -name '*-GHBAG-*' -exec bash -c 'echo mv $0 ${0/GHBAG/stream-agg}' {} \;
```

As I run this command, I see some outputs like this

```
mv ./report-GHBAG-1B ./report-stream-agg-1B
mv ./reoprt-GHBAG-0.5B ./report-stream-agg-0.5B
```

However at the end, when I run `ls`, I see the old file names.

Comment: A better question for most people who google this is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-in-unix

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You are echo'ing your 'mv' command, not actually executing it. Change to:

```
find . -name '*-GHBAG-*' -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0/GHBAG/stream-agg}' {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But, better surround those variables in `"` if you have `<whitespace>` on filenames. `mv "$0" "${0/GHBAG/stream-agg}"`.

Comment: @erickb great catch =)

Comment: I had no idea you could perform substitutions on variables in bash like this. Fantastic!

Comment: Could you please explain  why just this: find . -name '*-GHBAG-*' -exec mv ${0} ${0/GHBAG/stream-agg} {} \; doesn't work and a bash -c is required?

Comment: @VishalSaxena - bash is doing the string substitution here, not find - without bash you wouldn't be able to generate the new file name

Answer (score 37):

I would suggest using the `rename` command to perform this task. `rename` renames the filenames supplied according to the rule specified as a Perl regular expression.

In this case, you could use:

```
rename 's/GHBAG/stream-agg/' *-GHBAG-*
```

Comment: Thanks. It is much simpler but I was playing with `exec`

Comment: Certainly, `find` with `-exec` has the advantage of searching recursively down the directory, which rename cannot. But `rename` will be faster as it will not spawn a process for each individual file to be renamed.

Comment: @anumi `man find` shows `-exec command {} +` as option to execute only one instance on all found files. Although, I don't know whether it's useful with the example in original question.

Comment: @F-3000: The command would be `find . -name '*-GHBAG-*' -exec rename 's/GHBAG/stream-agg/' {} +` and it would do the job admirably, even if the file names contain spaces or newlines.

Comment: This would be great for small filesets. For handing many many files  use 'find' because this (or an 'ls' solution ) wont be able to evaluate the wildcards with so many files.

Comment: Not sure if it's because I was using another version of rename, I had to use `rename GHBAG stream-agg *-GHBAG-*`

Answer (score 20):

In reply to anumi's comment, you could in effect search recursively down directories by matching '**':

```
rename 's/GHBAG/stream-agg/' **/*-GHBAG-*
```

Comment: I tried this, and it worked only for one path out of several subdirectories. `find . -name "*:*"` still gave a list of files after running `rename -v 's/:/-/' **/*:*`, and second rename-run gave "_No such file or directory_" notify. (Debian 6)

Comment: rename is not universal unix command.

Answer (score 2):

This works for my needs, replacing all matching files or file types. Be warned, this is a very greedy search

```
# bashrc
function file_replace() {
  for file in $(find . -type f -name "$1*"); do
    mv $file $(echo "$file" | sed "s/$1/$2/");
  done
}
```

I will usually run with `find . -type f -name "MYSTRING*"` in advance to check the matches out before replacing.

For example:

```
file_replace "Slider.js" "RangeSlider.ts"

renamed:    packages/react-ui-core/src/Form/Slider.js -> packages/react-ui-core/src/Form/RangeSlider.ts
renamed:    stories/examples/Slider.js -> stories/examples/RangeSlider.ts
```

or ditch the filetype to make it even greedier

```
file_replace Slider RangeSlider

renamed:    packages/react-ui-core/src/Form/Slider.js -> packages/react-ui-core/src/Form/RangeSlider.js
renamed:    stories/examples/Slider.js -> stories/examples/RangeSlider.js
renamed:    stories/theme/Slider.css -> stories/theme/RangeSlider.css
```