# globally replace text to rename multiple files in sublime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rename, sublimetext

I'm working on a rails 4 app for which I need to change one of my model's names. This translates into changing a lot of other files such as the controller, view, etc.

I already generated a migration to change the table name. Then changed all `owner` to `user` inside all files within my app's directory using the global find and replace (i.e. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

As a final step I only need to **rename** the **file names** as well for example the model from `owner.rb` to `user.rb`, `owners_controller.rb` to `users_controller.rb`, etc.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a linux system instead of using sublime you could use a terminal, change directories to your project root and use:

```
find . -name '*owner*' -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0/owner/user}' {} \;
```

I found this technique here :), cheers

[find a pattern in files and rename them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290186/find-a-pattern-in-files-and-rename-them)