# Renaming Multiple Files in Unix

Tags: unix, file-rename

I have files in below format

```
EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_10022012_0630_Part1.expd
EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_10022012_0630_Part2.expd
EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_10022012_0630_Part3.expd
EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_10022012_0630_Part4.expd
```

I want to rename this with below files

```
EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_22052013_1000_Part1.expd
EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_22052013_1000_Part2.expd
EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_22052013_1000_Part3.expd
EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_22052013_1000_Part4.expd
```

It means I just want to rename the 10022012_0630 with 22052013_1000
what would be the commands and loop to be used to rename all the files in singe go

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename multiple files in Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-in-unix)

Comment: [`mmv - move/copy/append/link multiple files by wildcard patterns`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/mmv.1.html)

Answer (score 1):

This can work:

```
rename 's/10022012_0630/22052013_1000/' EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_10022012_0630_Part*
```

Given files with `EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_10022012_0630_Part*` pattern, it changes `10022012_0630` with `22052013_1000`.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe it is obvious, but what's the exactly meaning of `bash-fu`?

Comment: Kung-Fu, but with bash. See also google-fu (good in finding things on google) etc. Might be local jargon in Europe, don't know.

Comment: Oh I see! It makes sense and it's quite a funny way to show us playing with this scripting :D

Answer (score 1):

```
for OLDNAME in EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_10022012_0630_Part*.expd; do
  NEWNAME=`echo "$OLDNAME" | sed 's/10022012_0630/22052013_1000/'`
  mv "$OLDNAME" "$NEWNAME"
done
```

Comment: You can even do `NEWNAME=${OLDNAME/10022012_0630/22052013_1000}`. Based on [String Operations](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22664)

Comment: I tend to keep my stackoverflow answers more instructive than productive, so I took my time to put every step in a line on its own.

Answer (score 1):

A very effecient method, especially if you're dealing with thousands of files is to use bash for the string replacements and find for the lookup. This will avoid many useless forks/execve's and keep the process count down to a minimum:

```
for F in $(find /your/path/ -type f -name '*10022012_0630*'); do
  mv $F ${F/10022012_0630/22052013_1000};
done
```