# Complex Grep Issue

Tags: sed, grep, file-rename, filelist

I have a list full of filenames (in each line is one filename). How can I copy a file (for e.g. text.txt) multiple times and rename it (example1.txt, example2.txt so on). At the end I want multiple files with the content of text.txt but with the filenames of my list. Is this possible?

Comment: this has nothing to do with sed or grep

Comment: welcome to stack overflow.  It As @glennjackman pointed out, your question doesn't really directly relate to sed or grep (though I suppose you could write a script using those commands).  I would look into the rename command see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1086509/505191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read line; do
    cp text.txt "$line"
done < text.txt
```

You loop over all the lines in the file, and for each filename you invoke a separate `cp` command.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming no spaces in the filenames in your list:

```
for f in $list; do cp text.txt $f; done
```

If there are spaces, and assuming bash:

```
while IFS= read -r f; do cp text.txt "$f"; done <<< "$list"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|.*|cp -v text.txt "&"|e' list.txt
```