# Renaming recurively specified files

Tags: linux, bash, find, rename

My security cameras recorder (located in distant place), FTP`s to my server video files after any event. It automatically creates sudirs with name containing date of day. Using find and ffmpeg commands, server converts DAV file to AVI and remove DAV file. After that, each video file has name like this:

```
19.38.41-19.38.55[M][@0][0].dav.avi
```

I want to change above name to format like this:

```
19-38-41.avi
```

How can I do it in the same "find" command line

Comment: Better show your find command in your question.

Comment: This is my find command syntax: find $katalog -type f -name "*.dav" -exec ffmpeg -y -i {} -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 {}.avi >/dev/null 2>&1 \; -exec rm -f {} \;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find -name '*.dav.avi' -execdir rename ... {} \;
```

See ["Rename multiple files in Unix"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-in-unix) for the `rename` syntax.

Comment: I try something like this: find $katalog -type f -name "*.dav.avi" -execdir rename 's/.dav//' {} ;\ but the result was: find, no argument for -execdir (translation from my language)

Comment: Order of characters matters.