# Renaming files from a list using a shell script

Tags: shell

I would like to rename files from a list. This is the file format:

*Original name*

*New name*

```
000000000000402a.ogg
Dth_BrkNck_FOD_MALE_MALE_001
000000000000402c.ogg
Dth_BrkNck_FOD_MALE_MALE_002
000000000000402e.ogg
Dth_BrkNck_FOD_MALE_MALE_003
0000000000004030.ogg
Dth_BrkNck_FOD_MALE_MALE_004
```

I'm kinda new to shell scripts, so any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Forget about the shell or scripting for a while - how would *you* go about doing it, if you were to do it by hand? Once you have a plan ready, then it's all about scripting to that plan *SCNR* :-)

Comment: That said, did you take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-in-unix)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename multiple files in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-in-unix)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is not direct connection b/w `Original file name` and `New file name`, To rename a file,

`mv OriginalName NewName`

one way is to repeat the step for multiple files, ( we can create all commands in a notepad and paste it altogether)
or we can put it in a shell script , say `renamer.sh` as below and execute it,

```
cat renamer.sh
mv 000000000000402a.ogg Dth_BrkNck_FOD_MALE_MALE_001
mv 000000000000402c.ogg Dth_BrkNck_FOD_MALE_MALE_002
mv 000000000000402e.ogg Dth_BrkNck_FOD_MALE_MALE_003
mv 0000000000004030.ogg Dth_BrkNck_FOD_MALE_MALE_004
```

to execute :- `sh renamer.sh`