# Renaming multiple zip files with complex name using single command in linux

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, unix

I have multiple zip files in a folder with names like below:

> "abc.zip-20181002084936558425"

How to rename all of them with one command to get result like below:

> "abc-20181002084936558425.zip"

I want the timestamp before the extension for multiple filenames. Now every file has different timestamp so renaming should consider that. Can I rename multiple files like this using single command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename multiple files in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-in-unix)

Comment: What did you try so far, and why didn't it work the way you wanted?

Comment: Your question is not about programming, it is about Linux. I suggest to ask this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com, or on https://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1):

Providing your file are really all with the same name convention and you being in the right directory :

```
for i in *.zip-*; do newName=${i//.zip};mv $i $newName".zip";done
```

should do the trick.