# How to delete semicolons (;) in filenames by bash script with find?

Tags: bash, find

can anyone here tell me how I can make a `find` bash statement where I do a replace of Semicolons (;) in the filenames with blank? I have 200k files and some (about 2k) are with ; in filename which are not ok.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your current attempt. What problems are you facing?

Comment: Well I do not know how I can make a rename with the new filename where the ; is replace by space. I can do make a `find . -type f  -regextype egrep -regex '.+;.*'`

Comment: Are the files located in one directory or in several subdirectories?

Comment: several dirs, a whole big tree.

Comment: @Flimzy thanks a lot for your link - that helps great. I am still thinking about it  but on a good way

Comment: I could do it: `find . -type f -regextype egrep -regex '.+;.*' -exec rename 's/;/ ' {} \; `

Comment: Since this question was closed while I typed in my answer, I posted it under the duplicate post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-based-on-pattern-in-unix). I think it adds value there as well since I did not have success with the existing answers.