# How to rename multiple files in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Files are -

```
new_file.dat01,
new_file.dat02 and so on
```

i want to rename it as `new_file_01.dat, new_file_02.dat` and so on.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/631402/13792

Comment: @choroba the link you provided had a different renaming requirement . please read my question again, each file is to be renamed with different number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename multiple files based on pattern in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-based-on-pattern-in-unix)

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
for f in *file.dat*; do mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed -E 's/.dat(.*)/_\1.dat/')";done
```