# Remove string from all filenames in Linux folder

Tags: linux, macos

I have folder with 1000 JPG files like this:

```
17.png.jpg
341.png.jpg
882.png.jpg
997.png.jpg
1023.png.jpg
```

I need to rename all the list so the number will stay and remove just the ".png"
Result expected:

```
17.jpg
341.jpg
882.jpg
997.jpg
1023.jpg
```

What is the linux/mac command I should run?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename multiple files based on pattern in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-based-on-pattern-in-unix)

Answer (score 1):

If you have `bash` available, you can type

```
for i in *.png.jpg
do 
    mv "$i" "${i%.png.jpg}.jpg"
done
```