# Rename a specific part of filename

Tags: mv

Ciao,

i need rename the file created in one path with this syntax

20230103143408_device_activation.csv

in

20230103143408_attivazioniDevice.csv

This part will be replace _device_activation.csv into _attivazioniDevice.csv

How can i proceed?

mmv '*device_activation.csv' 'attivazioniDevice.csv'

Comment: do you want to keep the number before _device_activation.csv?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename multiple files based on pattern in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086502/rename-multiple-files-based-on-pattern-in-unix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, but a simple one that springs to mind is using `find`, `cut` and `xargs` like this...

```
find -type f -name '*device_activation.csv' | cut -d'_' -f1 | xargs -I % sh -c "mv %_device_activation.csv %_attivazioniDevice.csv"
```

Example usage...

```
ls -l
-rw-r--r--. 1 kcc users 0 Jan  3 15:39 20230103143407_device_activation.csv
-rw-r--r--. 1 kcc users 0 Jan  3 15:34 20230103143408_device_activation.csv
-rw-r--r--. 1 kcc users 0 Jan  3 15:39 20230103143409_device_activation.csv

find -type f -name '*device_activation.csv' | cut -d'_' -f1 | xargs -I % sh -c "mv %_device_activation.csv %_attivazioniDevice.csv"

ls -l
-rw-r--r--. 1 kcc users 0 Jan  3 15:39 20230103143407_attivazioniDevice.csv
-rw-r--r--. 1 kcc users 0 Jan  3 15:34 20230103143408_attivazioniDevice.csv
-rw-r--r--. 1 kcc users 0 Jan  3 15:39 20230103143409_attivazioniDevice.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one file, then hardcoding is the best solution. But if you have multiple files that end with CSV and want to rename all, Use this.

```bash
for file in *.csv;
 do mv $file ${file//_device_activation/_attivazioniDevice}; 
done
```

[image: terminal output before and after command run]